# Routing issue in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, routes, ubuntu-14.04, laravel-5

I am facing a strange issue with Larave 5.2 routing. Please find below details.

1) I have created HomeController with index() in it and set my route for "/". It was working fine.

2)After that I have renamed HomeController.php to Readme_couchbasenotes.php and created fresh HomeController. Since then my route is not working properly. Whenever I give HomeController@index it is looking for index in Readme_couchbasenotes.php.

routes.php:

```html
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/


//Route::auth();

Route::get('/','HomeController@index');
```

(Fresh) HomeController:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

class HomeController extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        return "Hello";
    }

}
```

Readme_couchbasenotes.php

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use CouchbaseCluster;

class HomeController_copy extends Controller {

    public function index() {


        /**
         * Different ways of doing CRUD operations on couchbase
         */
        
//---------------------------------------------------------        
        /**
         * To Create PRIMARY INDEX for data buckets 
         */
//        $query = 'CREATE PRIMARY INDEX `laravel-sample-primary-index` ON `laravel` USING VIEW;';
//        $res = \DB::connection()->bucket('laravel')->select($query);
//        var_dump($res);die;
//--------------------------------------------------------------
        
        
        /**
         * To Select set of records from data buckets
         */
//  Using \DB:: facades  
//          
//      $query = 'SELECT * FROM system:indexes WHERE name="beer-sample-primary-index";';
//        $res = \DB::connection('couchbase')->table('laravel')->where('name', 'Sri Harsha')->get();
//        $doc = Json_encode($res, True);
//        var_dump($doc);die;
//        
//  
//              
/**
 * Using OOP concepts with inbuilt couchbase methods
 */
        
        
        echo  "<br>After Retrieve<br>";
        echo  "------------------<br>";         
        $Cluster = New CouchbaseCluster('http://127.0.0.1:8091');
        $bucket = $Cluster->OpenBucket('laravel');

        Try {
            $result = $bucket->get('test2');
        } Catch (Exception $e) {
            Echo "CouchbaseException:" . $e->getMessage() . " \n";
        }
        $doc = $result->value;
        echo $doc->_id . "<br>" . $doc->name . "<br>";


        /**
         * To Update records into data buckets
         */
        echo "<br> After Update<br>";
        echo  "------------------<br>";
        $doc->name = 'Stranger';
        $u_result = $bucket->replace('test2', $doc);

        $doc2 = $bucket->get('test2')->value;
        echo $doc2->_id . "<br>" . $doc2->name . "<br>";
        

        /**
         *   To Insert records to data buckets
         */
        echo "<br> After Create.New Record Details<br>";
        echo  "----------------------------------------<br>";
        $data = [
            '_id' => 'test3_insert',
            'name' => 'Sri Harsha 3 insert'
            ];
        $bucket->Insert('test3', $data);
        $doc3= $bucket->get('test3')->value;
        echo $doc3->_id . "<br>" . $doc3->name . "<br>";
        
        /**
         * To Delete records from data buckets
         */     
        echo  "<br>After Delete<br>";
        echo  "------------------<br>";  
        $bucket->Remove('test1');  
        echo "<br>test1 has been deleted.";

        
//
    }

}
```

3) I even tried

php artisan cache:clear

php artisan clear-compiled

php artisan route:clear

Still it is looking for Readme_couchbasenotes.php whenever     HomeController is mentioned.

```html
srturaka@srturaka-pc:~/Desktop/work/dev.laravel5.2.com/public_html$ php artisan route:list

                                                                                                                                               
  [ErrorException]                                                                                                                             
  include(/home/srturaka/Desktop/work/dev.laravel5.2.com/public_html/app/Http/Controllers/Readme_couchbasenotes.php): failed to open stream:   
  No such file or directory
```

And one thing, this issue is only for HomeController because I renamed it, others are working fine which are new controllers.

Please suggest, if I miss anything. Thanks

Comment: Your `Readme_couchbasenotes.php` file must have the class with same name. Rename `HomeController_copy` to `Readme_couchbasenotes`

Comment: That doesn't answer ,my question. I want my route to point to HomeController.php file instead of Readme_couchbasenotes.php. Please understand the issue before giving suggestions.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes these kinds of issues arise due to the cache. So try running:

`composer dump-autoload`.

If this doesnot work try using:

`sudo composer dump-autoload`. (Since you are using ubuntu)

Running `php artisan config:clear` or
`php artisan cache:clear` might help as well

Answer (score 0):

change class name HomeController to Readme_couchbasenotes

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

class HomeController extends Controller {

```
public function index() {
    return "Hello";
}
```

}

Readme_couchbasenotes.php

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use App\Http\Requests;
 use CouchbaseCluster;

class Readme_couchbasenotes extends Controller {
  -----
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am looking for any internal cache file or entry which still need to deleted that I haven't deleted. Can you suggest?

Comment: Search in storage directory